# using domain name with expressjs on server rather than localhost

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, iis

OK, so I am successfully running expressjs on windows iis server localhost:5000 and getting the expected json response using the following code...

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const api_helper = require('./API_helper')
//const api_helper = require('./api')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

require('ssl-root-cas/latest')
  .inject()
  .addFile('./root.crt')
  .addFile('./****.crt')

// create a GET route
/* app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' });
  }); */

app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
  res.type('json')
    api_helper.make_API_call('https://*my_api_server*/api/company/')
    //api_helper.make_API_call('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => { 
        res.send(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

API_helper.js

```
const request = require('request')

module.exports = {
    /*
    ** This method returns a promise
    ** which gets resolved or rejected based
    ** on the result from the API
    */
    make_API_call : function(url){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
              if (err) reject(err)
              resolve(body)
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Screenshot of successful response using localhost:5000...

[image]

My question is, how would I get this to work using a domain name instead of localhost? When I use our https domain name, I get no response headers and just the raw html for server.js
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

When running on a port less than 1025, you need to run the server with escalated privileges.

If running on Windows ensure that your Command Line is running with Administrator Permissions.

With Linux:

```
sudo node server.js
```

Comment: He is using Windows and not Linux.

Comment: Im using VSCode on Windows terminal. sudo doesnt work. I use `node server.js`

Comment: Make sure to run VS Code with Administrator Privileges so that all you commands will run as Admin.

Comment: still getting same error when running server.js on port 443 with VScode running as admin Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: Do I not need to specify the domain name somewhere as currently its just defaulting to localhost

Comment: It's not necessary to specify the domain name.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use port 5000 whilst developing your application, then switch to 443 when in production.

Comment: I tried the following but wont load. site cant be reached. https://*mydomain*:5000/express_backend/